# Custom alias outside .zshrc but ZSH_CUSTOM doesn't work in kali

Tags: linux, zsh, kali-linux, alias, oh-my-zsh

> For reference this is not a duplicate: I reviewed other Q and A like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508524/zsh-add-aliases-outside-of-zshrc) but it doesn't work for me.

###### Background:

I'm using Kali in parallels.

To keep my `.zshrc` file tidy I decided to `mkdir my_zsh_aliases` then added `my_aliases.zsh` and it all looks like this:

---

`.zshrc`

```bash
ZSH_CUSTOM=~/my_zsh_aliases
```

and inside the `my_zsh_aliases` directory there's a file called:
`my_aliases.zsh`

```bash
alias ping='ping -c 4'

alias knock='python3 /home/parallels/Tools/knock/knockpy.py'
```

---

For some reason it doesn't work even after reloading the shell (reboot) & `source ~/.zshrc` command.

> The shell doesn't recognize knock as a command

EDIT: Including a link to the [Doc - about Customization](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Customization) for reference.

Comment: Have you tried to source the `my_aliases.zsh` inside your `.zshrc` file with `source $ZSH_CUSTOM/my_aliases.zsh`?

Comment: @Pixelbog According to the documentation they link, the sourcing of files in `$ZSH_CUSTOM`  should be handled by ohmyzsh.  I believe the question is why this does not seem to work as advertised.